# Fastest math programming language?

Tags: performance, math, compression

I have an application that requires millions of subtractions and remainders, i originally programmed this algorithm inside of C#.Net but it takes five minutes to process this information and i need it faster than that.

I have considered perl and that seems to be the best alternative now. Vb.net was slower in testing. C++ may be better also. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: C# typically gets decent math speeds, on small data sets. C or C++ for larger ones. Perl is almost never faster. Haskell or Mathlab or something along those lines may give significant gains, but will take a lot of translation. I'd benchmark C(++) first.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." - Maybe you should post your problem and/or algorithm. Most often a tuning in the algorithm brings far more, than switching the programming language (esp you already use C#.Net - which isnt the slowest). And if you want to switch to a programming language that is often used for numerics, take the good old FORTRAN (but dont say, we hadnt warned you). Due to some properties of the languages, often optimizations are possible, that are not possible with e.g. standard C/C++ code.

Comment: Good idea, move it from an at least partly compiled language to an interpreted language. That should boost performance incredibly!

Comment: Usually sarcasm is followed by a helpful suggestion. Especially on a Q&A website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some calculations are regular enough to take profit of GPGPUs: recent graphic cards are essentially specialized massively parallel numerical co-processors. For instance, you could code your numerical kernels in [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/). Otherwise, learn [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (not some earlier version of the C++ standard) or C. And in many cases [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) could be nearly as fast as C++ but much easier to code with.

Perhaps your problem can be handled by [scilab](http://www.scilab.org) or [R](http://www.r-project.org/), I did not understand it enough to help more.

And you might take advantage of your multi-core processor by e.g. using [Pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) or [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface)

At last, the Linux operating system is perhaps better to deal with massive calculations. It is significant that most super computers use it today.

Answer (score 8):

1. You need a compiled language like Fortran, C, or C++. Other languages are designed to give you flexibility, object-orientation, or other advantages, and assume absolutely fastest performance is not your highest priority.
2. Know how to get maximum performance out of a single thread, and after you have done so investigate sharing the work across multiple cores, for example with MPI. To get maximum performance in a single thread, one thing I do is single-step it at the machine instruction level, to make sure it's not dawdling about in stuff that could be removed.

Comment: And FORTRAN used to run circles around both C and C++ when I was doing scientific computing.  They've changed the language a lot since then, so I don't know if it's still true.

Comment: @duffymo: I could actually question that since I've worked (& still do) a lot with all of them. It all comes down to which one generates the best assembly code. Fortran had a big head start of course. My main co-worker is a big believer in Fortran, and I have to keep showing him how it isn't the language so much as what the program actually does, where the rubber meets the road.

Comment: @duffymo: LAPACK routine [DGEMM](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/dgemm.f.html) is my canonical example. Optimized to the teeth, right? Well, if you use it on matrices that aren't very big, you find it spending a large fraction of its time (half or more) in calls to [LSAME](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/lsame.f.html#LSAME.1). When I saw that, I just coded a special-purpose routine and saved all that time.

Answer (score 4):

If execution speed is the highest priority, that usually means Fortran.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Julia](https://julialang.org/): its killing feature is being easy to code in a high level concise way, while keeping performances at the same order of magnitude of Fortran/C.

Comment: For some comparassion with C, see: https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/julia-gcc.html. The best thing about Julia is that this language make easy to optimize and, since it makes use its multiple dispatch capabilities, it optimizes code on the first run, which makes it looks like C after the first run.

Answer (score 0):

[PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) is the best I have used so far. It's written in C.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [DMelt mathematical program](http://jwork.org/dmelt/). The program calls Java libraries. Java virtual machine can optimize long mathematical calculations for you.

Answer (score -1):

The standard tool for mathmatic numerical operations in engineering is often Matlab (or as free alternatives octave or the already mentioned scilab).